# Answers from quiz, why this answer is correct in particular?

Tags: perfect-aspect, progressive-aspect

#### First answer:

- ✅ Have you always *been living* in a big city?
  (**ʀɪɢʜᴛ ᴀɴꜱᴡᴇʀ**)
- ❌ Have you always *lived* in a big city? 
   (**ᴡʀᴏɴɢ ᴀɴꜱᴡᴇʀ**)

#### Second answer:

- ✅ By the end of August they’ll *have been working* on the new bridge for over eighteen months.
   (**ʀɪɢʜᴛ ᴀɴꜱᴡᴇʀ**)
- ❌ By the end of August they’ll *have been worked* on the new bridge for over eighteen months.
   (**ᴡʀᴏɴɢ ᴀɴꜱᴡᴇʀ**)

To me it seems as if both answers should be valid for both questions,
so could you please explain what’s wrong with the ones they said were wrong?

1. What’s wrong with asking whether you *have always lived* in a big city?
2. What’s wrong with saying that they’ll *have been worked* on the new
   bridge for over eighteen months?

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  If you are on a face-to-face learning programme, then it would be best to ask your teacher, who could explain more clearly and personally.  Also, could you say whether you have taken any steps to find out for yourself?

Comment: On the face of it,I’d say they are wrong about the first answer. “always lived” not “always been living”.

Comment: I agree. For the first question, either answer is possible, but B is much more likely. The second question (if you have reproduced it correctly) is answered correctly: _They'll have been worked_ is passive, and makes no sense in the context. If it's supposed to read _they'll have worked_, then either answer is good, depending on whether the speaker is choosing to draw attention to the continuing process or to regard it as a completed process.

Comment: [grammar correction: **Why is this answer correct?**]

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with any of the options to **question 1**, but they can mean different things in specific contexts. So maybe the question asker made a bit of a mistake, or the question was asked in a specific context *(I don't know)*.

As for **question 2**, it is correct to say "have been working", because it is in the *"present perfect continuous"* form.

The [present perfect continuous form](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/present-perfect-continuous-i-have-been-working) requires the verb to be in the *-ing* form, which is why **"have been worked"** is incorrect.